# C++ reading incorrectly from file

Tags: c++

So, i ran this program and the answer i expected was 26 but got -52 instead. Please explain why the code is reading the character incorrectly.

```
char x = 26;
ofstream ofile("file.txt");
ofile << x;
ifstream ifile("file.txt");
char y;
ifile >> y;
cout << (int)y;
```

Comment: Did you do any error checking to make sure the I/O succeeded?

Comment: You might also want to open the files in binary mode. Closing the output file before opening the input file is also likely a good idea

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write non-text data, you should open the file in binary mode:

```
ofstream ofile("file.txt", ios_base::binary);
```

A good practice is to check if the file was actually opened successfully:

```
ofstream ofile("file.txt", ios_base::binary);
if (!ofile) return -1;
```

Until you close the file, there's a high chance the buffer is not flushed, so there's no point in reading the file in another stream before you close it:

```
ofile << x;
ofile.close();
```

A good idea is to finish the output to `cout` with `endl`:

```
cout << (int) y << endl;
```

So you need something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char x = 26;

    ofstream ofile("file.txt", ios_base::binary);
    if (!ofile) return -1;
    ofile << x;
    ofile.close();

    ifstream ifile("file.txt", ios_base::binary);
    if (!ifile) return -1;
    char y;
    ifile >> y;
    cout << (int) y << endl;
    ifile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `.close()` will flush any remaining data to the file. `endl` will also, but see [std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) **Notes** section for a few considerations.

Comment: `endl` is not normally better than a simple new line, it is not necessary to flush most terminals which are line buffered anyway

Answer (score 3):

When you write to an `ofstream` the data you've written isn't written directly to the file but held into an in memory buffer, the buffer will only be written to the file when the buffer is full, you seek the stream, flush the stream or close the stream.

Also note that if you aren't writing plain text it is safer to open the file in binary mode to ensure your exact data is read/written. You should also use `read` and `write` rather than the formatted i/o functions (or `get` and `put` for single characters).

It is also a good idea to add some error checking.

```
char x = 26;
ofstream ofile("file.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
ofile.put(x);
if (!ofile)
{
  std::cout << "write failed\n";
  return;
}
ofile.close();
ifstream ifile("file.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
char y;
ifile.get(y);
if (!ifile)
{
  std::cout << "read failed\n";
  return;
}
cout << (int)y << "\n";
```

Having tested on Windows the two required changes are

1. Opening `ifile` in binary mode
2. Closing/flushing `ofile` before opening `iflie`

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want.

```
    char x = 26;
    ofstream ofile("file.txt");
    ofile << x;
    ofile.close ();       // <- closing the file
    ifstream ifile("file.txt");
    char y;
    ifile >> y;
    cout << "Value: " << (int)y << endl;
    return 0;
```

In this case it you may be reading something that's not yet written to disk (due to buffering.)

Output:

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -g main.cc -o main -Wpedantic && ./main
Value: 26
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ hexdump file.txt 
0000000 001a                                   
0000001
```

Comment: i'm using MSVC compiler and still getting -52 instead of 26

Comment: @AkshitBansal Ups! Not a MS user sorry. It shouldm't behave like you say even in Windows though.